# Unable to use Context.GpuContext in AleaTK because a refrence to an assembly is missing. C#

Tags: c#, gpu

I am programming a simple neural network following one of the examples provided on the AleaTK guide website, but when I attempt to use Context.GpuContext, it says "The type gpu is defined in an assembly that is not referenced." I am using Context.GpuContext in order to declare a variable to be used later.

```
var ctx = Context.GpuContxet(0);
```

The recommended solution provided is to add a reference to Alea 3.0.0.0 in the assemblies, but I am unable to find a web.conf or a system.web file to edit assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

[Alea 3.0.4 nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Alea/)

By installing this package it will give you the assembly reference you are looking for

If you don't understand how to use *Nuget*

[Quickstart: Install and use a package in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/install-and-use-a-package-in-visual-studio)

Comment: I have installed Alea 3.0.4 through NuGet, but the error says that it needs 3.0.0.0 which does not exist as a previous version on NuGet. It only goes back to 3.0.1.

Comment: Maybe you coukd use a binding redirect?

Comment: How would I do that?